# while loading any values in the asp.net page most of the times Getting errors "400 Bad Request (Invalid Verb)"

Tags: java, c#, asp.net, vb.net

Getting this **Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)**

below attached the error screen shot.. its working fine in local. after hosting the IIS its not working.

[image]

Comment: No images please

Comment: The 400 Bad Request error is an HTTP status code that means that the request you sent to the website server, often something simple like a request to load a web page, was somehow incorrect or corrupted and the server couldn't understand it.

Comment: Best way is to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.  Compare the messages sent local where it is working with the one that is failing.  Look at the header messages and see if they are the same.  The http header are used to negotiate a common operating mode between the server and client.  So when you send a request the server responds back with a response recommending a operating mode or rejecting the requested mode.  Verify that the request/response is using HTTP 1.0 (not 1.1).  For example the server may work with both english and french.  The request can request either language.